# How can I forbid the Linux kernel from accessing a certain RAM disk?

Tags: linux, ramdisk

Can anyone tell me if the Linux kernel has access to RAM Disks and if so, how can we forbid it?

I want to have a RAM Disk that I'm the only one who has access and can change the information, and I want to be sure that the OS doesn't manipulate it.

EDIT :
i know that we can mount a ram disk an use it like a hard drive , but does OS have access to this ram disk and manipulate its content whenever it needs extra RAM for its processes ?

is there any other way that i can reserve a chunk of memory that OS has not access to it ?

EDIT 2 : 
is there a way that i can stop ram disk data moving to swap space ?
i want to be sure that the Data i have written in this RAM Disk will always remain in RAM(memory)

and i also wanna know if kernel or other processes overwrite RAM Disk DATA ? IN CASE THEY NEED MORE MEMORY !!

Comment: Could you explain how *you* have access to the RAM disk *without* using *OS services*. Please **edit your question** to improve it. I believe you don't understand the role of an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), but I might misunderstood your question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : what about now ?

Comment: Still very unclear. I still believe you aver very confused. I tried to improve my answer.

Comment: **why do you ask?** What is the actual use case? Edit your question to be much more specific and concrete!

Comment: How did you create the RAM disk?.

Comment: You should not have re-asked [nearly the same question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/217853/50557) twice. You should have edited this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible because it's the Linux kernel that creates and manages the RAM disk.

Responding to a later amendment to your question, asking *how to reserve a chunk of memory that the OS cannot access.* The OS manages all your access to the hardware. That is - by definition - part of what it's there for. So, no, it's not possible to reserve a chunk of memory without the OS reserving it for you.

If you have assigned a portion of memory to your RAM disk, content written to that RAM disk will not get overwritten. Your available memory is shared between the RAM disk and everything else.

Comment: A hypervisor below the OS can reserve such a RAM portion that is not available to the OS kernel above.

Comment: @Nils, yes I suppose so

Answer (score -1):

Often, what you call RAM disks are on Linux [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file systems. Today, [`ramfs` is obsolete](http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk), so there is no reason to use `ramfs`; better use `tmpfs`

<sup>(But indeed, you have been able in the [past](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1245395) to buy real RAM "disk" hardware; AFAIK this is obsolete technology; today you'll better buy SSD).</sup>

A `tmpfs` file system on Linux uses [*virtual memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), not RAM. So if you have enough swap space, and if RAM is tight (e.g. because some process is allocating a lot of memory using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, perhaps thru `malloc`...) the kernel would move some of the the `tmpfs` data to swap space in its [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) subsystem.

Read also [linuxatemyram](http://linuxatemyram.com/).

I don't understand why you want to "reserve a chunk of memory that OS has not access to it". You'll just *waste* RAM since by definition nothing could be able to access that chunk of memory (*all* the memory is by definition managed by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)). The only use case is when you know that some part of the RAM is physically broken (and you know which part and which *physical* address). Then you can configure your system to avoid it (but I forgot the details). Or perhaps you are running Linux over some [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) which does use that RAM in some other system VM -e.g. running another OS like FreeBSD?

My feeling is that you don't understand what is an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), what is an OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29), what are [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), what is [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), what is an [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (so your question does not make much sense!). You need to read a lot. Start with [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and follow all the links I gave here.

You might want a `tmpfs` file system reserved to some applications. You could `chown` the file tree in it to some user dedicated to these applications. See [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), ....

You might be interested by [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) (it will lock some virtual memory segment into physical RAM), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [msync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html), [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html), or (to deal with file contents) [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)

If you want to get some (virtual) memory and be sure that it is in RAM, get that memory range using `mmap` (e.g. with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, or with `MAP_FILE|MAP_LOCKED|MAP_SHARED` if you give a file segment) then lock that memory segment in physical RAM using `mlock` (unless you used `mmap` with `MAP_LOCKED` which does an implicit `mlock`)

<sup>You won't get any help unless you show some commands and some code related to your issue.</sup>

Comment: hi 
actually i want to cache some data into some RAM Disks and i don't want them to be moved to swap or ..... .
all i want is to be sure that my data in RAM Disk will remain and wont be changed or removed by kernel or other processes.
you got me ?

Comment: You should **edit your question** and **explain even more why** you don't want to move data to swap. Often, the kernel is better than you in deciding what should be moved to swap... What is your exact use case? We can't guess it!

Comment: you know , i want to use this chunk as cache and when the data is moved to swap space read/write speed would decrease and  its not what im looking for !!
you didnt answer my first question !
1. how can i stop this " moving to swap space " ?

Comment: and i also wanna know  that is this possible that kernel overwrite data in ram disks ?

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't add comments. I won't tell more unless you improve your question and motivate it.

Comment: Did you follow all the links I gave you? They give some answers, and most importantly, they will enable you to improve your (still meaningless) question - or ask a more focused one... **You are very confused** and you misunderstand a lot of things... So take time to read.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There is a *significant* difference between a tmpfs and a ramdisk.

Comment: Yes, and `tmpfs` are always better than `ramfs`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - that's not necessarily true. ramdisks are blockdevs. tmpfs has no such thing. block devices are always better when a block dev is required.